# Excel vba Run-time error '13' on code that was previously working

Tags: vba, excel-2003

I'm having problems with the below code in Excel vba. Previously the line `rSurname = Range ("A" + numrows).Value` was working fine but i've added in the code the check whether the value already exists in the range "D:D" and now I'm getting the Run-time error 13 message

Essentially what I'm trying to do is:

1. Check that a Surname has only 5 characters
2. If a surname has less than 5 chars, pad to 5 with spaces
3. If a surname has more than 5 chars, trim to 5 chars
4. Add a numeric suffix padded to 4 numbers (ie 0001)
5. Check that the output doesn't exist already, and if not print to range "D:D"
6. If value does exist, increment suffix and repeat check until value unique

My code is below

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click()

Dim rSurname, rOutput, sLength, numrows, sFindString As String
Dim nSuffix As Integer
Dim rRange As Range
Dim iLength As Long



numrows = 1
    'Set Cell A2 as first cell range
    Range("A2").Select
    'Set loop to stop when en empty cell is reached
    Do
    'Increment numrows
    numrows = numrows + 1
    'Set Surname value
    rSurname = Range("A" + numrows).Value
    'Check Surname Letter Count and ensure 5 chars in Surname
    iLength = Len(rSurname)
    If iLength > 5 Then
             rSurname = Left(rSurname, 5)
    ElseIf iLength = 4 Then
        rSurname = rSurname & " "
    ElseIf iLength = 3 Then
        rSurname = rSurname & "  "
    ElseIf iLength = 2 Then
        rSurname = rSurname & "   "
    ElseIf iLength = 1 Then
        rSurname = rSurname & "    "
    Else
        rSurname = rSurname
End If


'Set Suffix value
nSuffix = 1
    Do
    'Combine Surname and suffix
    rOutput = rSurname & Format(nSuffix, "0000")
            'Check whether Output in list range
            sFindString = "rOutput"
            If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
                With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
                    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                 rOutput = rOutput
                Else
                    nSuffix = nSuffix + 1
                End If
            End With
        End If
        Loop

    'Add Outputs to Columns
    Range("B" + numrows).Value = rSurname
    Range("C" + numrows).Value = nSuffix 
    Range("D" + numrows).Value = rOutput

    Loop Until IsEmpty(rSurname)
End Sub
```

Comment: The data range i'm using is:
A
To
Cox
Cook
Smith
Holtam
Fraser
Smithson
Smithson
Smithson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a much simpler version:

```
Sub CreateStrings()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, s As String
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim v

    Set rng = Range([A2], Me.[A2].End(xlDown))
    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        s = cl.Value
        If Len(s) < 5 Then
            s = s & Space(5 - Len(s))
        Else
            s = Left(s, 5)
        End If
        i = 1
        v = Application.Match(s & Format(i, "0000"), Me.[D:D], 0)
        Do While Not IsError(v)
            i = i + 1
            v = Application.Match(s & Format(i, "0000"), Me.[D:D], 0)
        Loop
        cl.Offset(, 3) = s & Format(i, "0000")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried running this but i'm getting the Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error on the 'Set rng' line. Any ideas?

Comment: Because  your original post was a sub called `TestButton_Click` I assumed you were coding this in a Sheet module.  If this is not the case then `Me.` will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

probably better to get rit off the filter and use a worksheet function like

```
iFoundStrings = 
   Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D"), 
   FindString)
```